# Sorting infinite scrolling list items implemented using Paging library

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll, android-paging

Let's say I have implemented an infinite scrolling list using Paging Library, but now I want to give the user an option to sort the data at client side, how can I do it? For example, I have movies data, the Paging library is working fine to load all movies, but how can I sort the movies based on say rating or release date.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: in infinite scrolling data repeats . If you sort then same data will come more than once consecutively

Comment: but how can I sort the data if it is coming from network in set of 10 items, if I sort one batch, when the next batch comes, it will be sorted but only between those 10, but I want that when next 10 items come, all the 20 items get sorted before displaying in the list. How can I achieve that, is it even possible?

Comment: Hi @kevin, maybe you could have an array that stores the data you already have and adds the new data that's just come. Sorting this array, clearing the adapter and give it the sorted array could possible work maybe, not sure, but that sounds like too much effort for the front end to handle whereas it could be easier to be done on the server side where you could simply send a key parameter saying you want the data to be returned sorted a certain way, such as by rating or date.

Comment: @FrancislainyCampos what if he didn't make the api.If he s using third party api how can he send a parameter and get all data sorted

Comment: Good point @kevin. Didn't consider the idea of a third party library. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this method but hope it works .
Assuming you use `RecyclerView` to show the list (because it is much easier in recyclerView)

When you get the first ten item from server and you choose to sort it.Lets say by name(ascending) .You have to use two ArrayList here:
1:finalArrayList  :- which contains all the whole list
2:updateArrayList :- which has the latest ten result

when you choose to sort (onButtonClick)

```
      updateArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        updateArrayList.addAll(finnalArrayList);


 Collections.sort(updateArrayList, new Comparator<StoreModel>() {
      public int compare(StoreModel obj1, StoreModel obj2) {
           // ## Ascending order
           if (sortingBy == 0) {
                     return obj1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(obj2.getName());
 }});
adapter.clear();
adapter.addAll(updateArrayList);
```

Run this code only when the button is clicked

Now when you scroll down and more data comes

```
 updateArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
 updateArrayList.add(StoreModel)//Add the latest ten data from the response
```

and sort it before sending it to adapter

```
 Collections.sort(updateArrayList, new Comparator<StoreModel>() {
      public int compare(StoreModel obj1, StoreModel obj2) {
           // ## Ascending order
           if (sortingBy == 0) {
                     return obj1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(obj2.getName());
 }});
 adapter.addAll(updateArrayList);
```

hope you got it and hope it works.Cheers:)

Comment: Hi @kevin, just to make clear, I am using android Paging library, and the adapter is PagedListAdapter where I a using submitList() method to set the data to Adapter, so your solution won't work for me